# Java Script form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

so what I try is to show an error "First name must be filled out" as a text called "check", not as an alert... 
Please help:)

```
  <html>
  <body>

 <form name="myForm" action="page.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  First name: <input type="text" name="box>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
<p id="check"></p>


<script>

function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["box"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("First name must be filled out") ="check"; // I tried to send alert as text... 
    return false;
 }
 } 

  </script>

  </body>
   </html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

`alert("First name must be filled out") ="check";`

to

```
document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = 'First name must be filled out';
```

Answer (score 2):

As pure **Javascript** Solution you could replace the `alert` with the following code:

```
document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = "First name must be filled out";
```

In **jQuery** you could try:

```
$( "#check" ).html( 'First name must be filled out' );
```